.NET build failing during getting Nuget packages from Artifactory repo
I'm setting up Jenkins build pipeline for .NET Core. The build step is failing because it can't get all dependent Nuget packages from our local Artificatory repo. I assume that in general the process is set up correctly. I can get some of the packages. However I'm failing to get librdkafka Nuget.
1>Done Building Project "/opt/app-root/src/ProjectAPP/ProjectAPP.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
"/opt/app-root/src/ProjectAPP/ProjectAPP.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
(Restore target) ->
/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/8.0.107/NuGet.targets(156,5): error : https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/central-nuget-remote/registration-semver2/librdkafka.redist/index.json [/opt/app-root/src/ProjectAPP/ProjectAPP.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Build process is running in docker container on OpenShift. Local build is working OK according to developers.
When I navigate /index.json I can get json:
{
    "count": 3,
    "items": [
        {
            "count": 64,
            "lower": "0.9.3-pre-20",
            "upper": "1.1.0",
            "@id": "https://artifactory.local:443/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/central-nuget-remote/registration-semver2/librdkafka.redist/page/0.9.3-pre-20/1.1.0.json"
        },
        {
            "count": 64,
            "lower": "1.2.0-RC1b",
            "upper": "1.9.0-RC10",
            "@id": "https://artifactory.local:443/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/central-nuget-remote/registration-semver2/librdkafka.redist/page/1.2.0-RC1b/1.9.0-RC10.json"
        },
        {
            "count": 42,
            "lower": "1.9.0-RC12",
            "upper": "2.5.0",
            "@id": "https://artifactory.local:443/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/central-nuget-remote/registration-semver2/librdkafka.redist/page/1.9.0-RC12/2.5.0.json"
        }
    ],
    "@id": "https://artifactory.local:443/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/central-nuget-remote/registration-semver2/librdkafka.redist/index.json"
}

If I navigate links inside I get:
*/librdkafka.redist/page/0.9.3-pre-20/1.1.0.json - correct response
{
    "count": 64,
    "lower": "0.9.3-pre-20",
    "parent": "https://artifactory.local:443/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/central-nuget-remote/registration-semver2/librdkafka.redist/index.json",
    "upper": "1.1.0",
    "items": [
.........

*/librdkafka.redist/page/1.2.0-RC1b/1.9.0-RC10.json - Failed
Failed to parse registration page for package: librdkafka.redist
for more information check the logs.

*librdkafka.redist/page/1.9.0-RC12/2.5.0.json - Failed
Failed to parse registration page for package: librdkafka.redist
for more information check the logs.

I asked our Artifacotry admin for logs, but he did not find any error there.
If I navigate Artifactory webgui, I can find librdkafka.redist.2.5.0.nupkg in central-nuget-remote-cache repo. My assumtion is, that I'm missing older versions of librdkafka.redist. Is that true? How can I fix that?

It seems, there is issue with librdkafka setup in Nuget.org repository. If I try download Nuget with API V3, I gen error. If I try Nuget API V2 it works fine. I raised issue on GitHub. https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/issues/4801
